# making a directory in a directory based on the directory that already exists | shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I run a shell script that moves some directorys from one directory to another directory based on the first 2 digits for example: I have a directory filled with other directory's named like `180021`, `180043`, `170154`. I move these directory's to another on and put them in the year they belong in based on the first 2 digits. So for example `180021` and `180043` go to the directory `2018` but `170154` goes to the directory `2017`.

now I would like to create something that looks inside the `2018` and `2017` directory's and looks which files it contains. If it contains for example `180021` I want the script to create a directory called `180000-180100`. but when it contains the directory `180562` I want it to create the directory `180500-180600` If possible I would like to make it dynamic so it will work for the next "100" year

I have searched all over the internet but I couldn't find anything to help me, could anyone please help me.

thanks in advance,

Comment: "I have searched all over the internet but I couldn't find anything to help me" - Nothing?!

Comment: @GéCusters could you paste the code which is in your current shell script?

Comment: Build a list of your directories, loop on them.  Then check the first two digits and based on your logic outlined in your question, create them.  SO users will not write the entire thing for you, but will help you if you are stuck on some detail, which you can ask help on (with a good question).  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  This is a custom script you need, Google will not find something that does exactly that (unless you are VERY luck!).<

Comment: @Nic3500 thank you for your help, yea i understand this is a custom script I just couldnt find a way to do it but with this help i should be able to do it.